# add .gif to the end of the string if it is not already there

Tags: lua

Suppose I have a variable like

```
foo = "/this/is a/path/my file.gif"
bar = "/this/is a/path/my file"
```

I want to say that if string does not end with `.gif` then add `.gif` to the end of the string.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending `.gif` is trivial (`s = s .. ".gif"`). The remaining question is how to check whether the string ends with `.gif`. There are two ways to go about this: Either use `string.sub`

```lua
if not gif_path:find"%.gif$" then gif_path = gif_path .. ".gif" end
```

or pattern matching (`string.find` or `string.match`):

```lua
if gif_path:sub(-#".gif") ~= ".gif" then gif_path = gif_path .. ".gif" end
```

if you end up with many "ends with" checks, you should write your own string "ends with" function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
gif_path = "/this/is a/path/my file.gif"
if(gif_path:sub(-string.len(".gif")) ~= ".gif")
then
    gif_path = gif_path .. ".gif"
end
```